# Can Windows machines wake as fast as Mac?

Tags: mac, laptop, ssd, sleep, wake-up

My wife is a Mac user and I am a Windows user. When my wife opens the lid of her 2017 Macbook, **the computer is almost *instantly* awake and running**, with everything useable on the desktop. Even at its very slowest when the computer has not been touched in a while and programs were left on, it never takes more than 2 - 3 seconds max for her computer to wake up and be ready to go.

I bought a new laptop yesterday which is my first upgrade in 7 years. One of the things I was most excited for is that this will be my first laptop with an SSD, so I was expecting my wake times from sleep or boot times from being completely off to be almost non-existent, in the same way that those of my wife's Mac are.

Despite this being a 2023 ASUS laptop running Windows 11 with 32GB of RAM, a 1TB SSD, and a AMD Ryzen 9 7940HS processor, the time to wake from sleep is still not as fast as a Mac's... It still takes around 5 - 6 seconds of Windows loading before the desktop comes up, and there still is a bit of lag in starting to use programs when I'm first using them from sleep again.

**My primary question is how Macs are able to achieve such blazing fast wake times, even in their 2017 models? My long-shot question is whether there is a way to make a Windows machine emulate the ultra-fast wake times of Macs where I put in my passcode and the desktop is up only a second or less?**

FWIW, in case anyone is wondering, yes, "fast startup" is enabled in my Control Panel settings on my laptop, and no, I don't have a dozen different applications open or running in the background because this laptop is brand new and I have installed almost nothing on it so far. My 5 - 6 second wake times are with 0 - 2 programs open and nearly no "startup programs" allowed in my settings.

Comment: My 9th Generation Intel desktop reboots within 3 seconds. I have laptops that reboot within 2 seconds. They both instantly awake from hybrid sleep. These times are the times from the logo to being able to interact with the machine. If you increase the amount of applications that automatically start on the Apple device the time would also increase.

Comment: With a new computer you are likely currently saddled with unnecessary bloat installed by the manufacturer/brand. A good 1st step with any computer is to reset it fully, uninstall crapware, update drivers, and the like. A modern Windows computer should be pretty fast to wake, BUT, taking two high-end computers, one Mac and one "Wintel", optimized properly, the Mac will likely still have the performance edge. This is largely due to the direct integration of Apple hardware and software, which has always had some edge.

Comment: But, besides startup, a properly optimized Wintel computer and Apple computer at similar price points should perform comparably overall, with any differences being pretty small.

Comment: As another week has passed with my new laptop, it seems to be booting... faster, strangely? Maybe it was slower at the beginning for a period because it had different pieces of software that it kept finding in the background needed to be updated?

Comment: Your complaint is not uncommon, and while there are ways to minimize wake time, sometimes their efficacy is not great. When I worked at Dell HQ (Round Rock, TX) people would mostly show up to meetings with their laptops held with the lid open to avoid long resume from sleep issues. You'd think Dell would be able to figure that out, but over the several years I worked at Dell (2006 - 08) that never changed. Odd that it is still an issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Search for **Edit power plan** in the search menu.
2. On the top address bar click **Power Options**
3. On the left track click **Choose what the power buttons do**
4. For each column **On battery** and **Plugged in** select the option **Sleep**.

It should look something like this:

[image]

You may need to enable the Hibernation file too; Open command prompt as administrator and run:

```
powercfg /h on
```

---

This is the closest you'll get to that fast power-on.

Keep in mind that this state keeps the RAM in low consumption mode so when you fire up the computer it immediately kicks into action.

Comment: Just stressing, " this state keeps the RAM in low consumption mode." If left plugged into the mains, that's not an issue, but if on battery, it can deplete the battery over some hours.

Comment: Bummer, looks like these options are already turned on on my machine. Maybe it's just a  mysteriously slow computer somehow? Thanks for the suggestion!